# Django Class Based Generic Views URL Variable Passing

Tags: regex, django, url, variables, view

Question is quite simple.

Let's say I have an URL config with line:

```
url(r'^models/(?P<model_group_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page>\d+)/$', 'Group'),
```

And I want to access `model_group_id` variable inside

```
class Group(ListView)
```

View.

On simple views I would just change `Group` description to:

```
class Group(ListView, model_group_id):
```

And it would work. Now it says that `model_group_id` is not defined. So how to pass variables from url regex to class-based view?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access positional arguments in `self.args` and name-based arguments in `self.kwargs`.

```
class Group(ListView): 

    def get_queryset(self):
        model_group_id=self.kwargs['model_group_id']
        ...
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) for more info.