# How to pass a variable in the URL in class based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have the following event feed (using `Django-ical`)

```
class EventFeed(ICalFeed):

    def items(self):
        meeting_id = self.kwargs['meeting_id']
        return Meeting.objects.get(id=meeting_id)
```

I am trying to pass the `meeting_id` through the URL conf like so:

```
url(r'^meetings/(?P<meeting_id>\d+)/$', EventFeed()),
```

However this returns `'EventFeed' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`?

Comment: Surely get_queryset should return a queryset, not an ID?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure - I am trying to follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/8925554/2429989

Comment: But that doesn't say to return the ID. It's just saying that's where you get it from, so that you can continue and use it to query the model and return the queryset.

Comment: Thanks, so I can use `self.kwargs` in any definition? I have simplified my question with edits, unfortunately I am still experiencing a problem in picking up the attribute...

Comment: django-ical says it's based on the syndication framework, which has nothing at all to do with class-based views, and it doesn't use kwargs at all. I'm not even sure what you are trying to do; this is supposed to be a feed, ie a list of events, not a single detail.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, I am trying to filter the feed to one event so I can use it to produce a single .ics file for that instance. Is there a better approach you could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel points out in the comments, this is a syndication framework. Therefore we need to use `get_object`, and to `filter` not `get` on the `Meeting` object:

```
class EventFeed(ICalFeed):

    def get_object(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return int(kwargs['meeting_id'])

    def items(self, meeting_id):
        return Meeting.objects.filter(id=meeting_id)
```